# Jquery load function isn't loading data from one html file to another

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to load my navigation bar and footer from my index.html to other pages for example about.html
both are in the same folder but for some reason, the load function will not work.

I am using Chrome if this may be related (but I also tried on Edge and Firefox with not success)

This is how my code looks like from the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo/soup.png">
    <title>Souplease - Delivering soup to your doorstep!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index-style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar" id="loadContent">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/logo/logo2.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-ul">
            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

And the about.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo/soup.png">
    <title>About Souplease</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about-style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loadContent').load('index.html');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loadContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks!!

**Edit:**

This is what I see from the Network tab:

[Network Tab #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yFzl.png)

[Network Tab #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L62tn.png)

[Console Tab #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAWoq.png)

Comment: any error shown in console ?

Comment: I am using Sublime, no errors. the about.html page is just blank

Comment: Can you see if the request actually made in the network tab?

Comment: @MoshFeu I updated the post with 2 screenshots,

Sorry I am a bit new in this and not sure what info would help for you to understand the issue.

Let me know if there is anything else I should add to the post and thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running the website with a local http server or open the file in the browser (look up to the url, is it start with `http://` or with `file://`)

Comment: I am running it locally - file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Souplease/about.html

Comment: I added another screenshot from Edge's console.